# Airflow - how to mount dags to Azure Storage Account

Tags: python, azure, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-scheduler

In my docker-compose.yml file, I currently mount the dags folder on a docker instance to the vm which it runs on.

```
volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
```

I want to host this on the cloud and ideally want to mount to an azure storage account. I have successfully set up remote logging to this storage account via a config on airflow.cfg, but I am unsure how to mount the filesystem for dags.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cheers for the suggestion . I ended up using Blob Fuse connector which is designed for blob store mounting.